# -Ек/-ик. Когда отсекаемая, а когда – неотсекаемая?

Tags: орфография

А почему иногда можно усекать гласную из этого окончания, и мы пишем *-ек* (1.), а иногда это мы не делаем, и мы пишем *-ик* (2.)? Есть какое-то суперправило?

1. Овражек, барашек, замочек, коточек.
2. Бидончик, ключик, кузнечик.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

См. [**«Полный академический справочник»**](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/#id-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%C2%A750) под ред. Лопатина:

> **§ 50**
>
> **–ек, −ик.** Следует различать уменьшительно-ласкательные
> суффиксы существительных мужского рода *–ек* (в безударной позиции)
> и *−ик, −чик* (всегда безударные). В суффиксе *−ек* гласный
> (проверяемый под ударением в словах типа *пенёк, творожо́к*) является
> беглым, а в суффиксах *−ик* и *−чик* гласный при склонении
> сохраняется. Таким образом, беглый гласный передается здесь
> буквой ***е*** (см. § 64), а небеглый – буквой ***и***,
> напр.: *овражек – овражка, кусочек – кусочка, ножичек – ножичка,
> барашек – барашка*, но *столик – столика, калачик – калачика,
> стаканчик – стаканчика*.
>
> По этому же правилу пишутся характерные для разговорной речи и
> просторечия образования на *−ик* с небеглым гласным суффикса и
> усеченной основой производящего слова
> типа *ве́лик* (велосипед), *телик* (телевизор), *видик* (видеомагнитофон), *шизик* (шизофреник),
> а также усеченные уменьшительные личные имена типа *Алик, Владик*.

Comment: Но почему иногда можно усечь, а иногда – нельзя?

Comment: Наверное, так исторически сложилось.